# N Staircase steps

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures

> Bilbo is at his friend's place and there are N steps. Bilbo, being a
>   thoughtful person, wanted to know in how many ways can he reach the
>   Nth stair if he takes 1 or 2 steps at a time. Note that he can not
>   take more than or equal to 2 consecutive 2 steps at a time. One way of
>   reaching Nth stair is different from another if he touches at least
>   one different stair.

Here is my code so far; I can't figure out how to not allow taking 2 steps, twice in a row.  Help?

```
public static int fibOptimized(int n) {
    int arr[] = new int[n + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = -1;
    }
    int output = fibHelper(n, arr);
    return output;
}

public static int fibHelper(int n, int[] arr) {
    if (n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (arr[n] > -1) {
        return arr[n];
    }
    arr[n] = fibHelper(n - 1, arr) + fibHelper(n - 2, arr);
    return arr[n];
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask].

Comment: You will get better response if you post your work so far and ask for *specific* help on the remaining part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your problem is the constraint against consecutive 2-step moves.  The problem requires that the function know one bit of status information: was the previous step (if any) a 2-step?  Simply include a Boolean flag in the parameter list.

```
int count_path(N, two_step) {
    ...
    count += count_path(N-1, false)
    if not two_step
        count += count_path(N-2, true)
```

Will that un-block your train of thought?

**EDIT AFTER ACCEPTANCE**

I added the `if` statement to make the application clear.